# Which controller does a partial in my `views/layouts` work with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried adding `@categories = Category.all` in my `ApplicationController`.

But when I click on one of my views, it doesn't work - it seems `@categories` is `nil` when it shouldn't be.

I would like to generate a menu in my `_navigation.html.erb` partial in my `layouts` folder.

Where do I declare the `@categories` instance variable to be used in a partial that will be used on all of my views if not in my `Application Controller`?

Thanks.

Comment: Another approach: https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use before_filter in application controller, it execute any method before the action you call

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :some_action

  def some_action
   @categories = Category.all
  end 
end
```

You should read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Answer (score 2):

If it's going to be used in all your views, maybe you can define a helper.

```
def all_categories
 @categories ||= Category.all
end
```

You can access it in all your views using all_categories.

**UPDATE:**

If you wish to define all_categories in your controller, use helper_method

```
helper_method :all_categories
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to look at it. I prefer using the `before_filter` in my `application_controller`. But as as thought exercise, I would want to put this in my application_helper, right? If so, this is clever.

Comment: Yup. You could add this to application helper.

Comment: Hrmm...so one question here, will this interfere with other controllers where my `@categories` variable is set as something else?

Comment: Nope. You'll be calling the method, not an instance variable. all_categories instead of @categories.